# How do I add custom field attributes with an inlineformset_factory?

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, django-forms

I have an 'inlineformset_factory', and I'm trying figure out how to set attributes for the individual fields. I haven't come up with any way to add them besides using javascript (which would be hacky and bad).

In the end I'd like something like:

```
<input id="id_authorbook_set-0-title" type="text" name="authorbook_set-0-title" maxlength="255" placeholder="Title" autofocus="autofocus">
```

I know adding custom attributes is possible when using normal Forms or even ModelForms with `attrs={'foo': 'bar', 'placeholder': 'Username'}`, but haven't been able to find any way to do the same with formset factories.

Is there a solution?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you needing to pass a value to the form used by the formset at runtime?

Comment: @Brandon Not really. I just need static attributes for certain fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe as working, the `attrs` argument, is passed to a form widget, which means you need form fields and thus a form.

`inlineformset_factory` is a `formset_factory` for ModelForms.

Tying the two together, you need to define a custom `ModelForm` and pass that to the factory as the `form` argument.

You could also define a custom formset which iterates through the active forms, does the same overrides, and pass that to the `inlineformset_factory`.

```
class MyMF(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyMF, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'].widget.attrs = {'foo': 'bar'}

inlineformset_factory(form=MyMF)
```